# kUTTypeURL undefined — Use of unresolved identifier 'kUTTypeURL' in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm having trouble getting a sharing extension to work. I have the following in my sharing controller.

```
let item: NSExtensionItem = self.extensionContext.inputItems[0] as NSExtensionItem
let itemProvider: NSItemProvider = item.attachments[0] as NSItemProvider
var URL: NSString
if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeURL) {
  itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeURL, options: nil, completionHandler:   {(url: NSURL, error: NSError) in
     URL = url.absoluteString
  })
}

self.extensionContext.completeRequestReturningItems(nil, completionHandler: nil)
```

This gives me the error `Use of unresolved identifier 'kUTTypeURL'` on the line `if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeURL) {`.

It [seems to be defined](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/UTI_Concrete_Types) as a constant in Swift, but I can't seem to access it. Is it part of an enum? Do I have to import something to get access to it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `import MobileCoreServices`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just so this question has an answer:

Add `import MobileCoreServices` to your source file.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 15+**

Use `UTType.url.identifier` instead.

```
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.url.identifier) {
...
}
```